# How can Java Files.walkFileTree() be used in a multiThread fashion using the FileVisitor interface?

Tags: java, multithreading

Needing to scan an entire computer for files, I would like to start a Files.walkFileTree( startingFolder, FileVisitor) on each physical drive on a computer. However, I am finding the the FileVisitor override methods are getting confused. If I start only one thread, every things works fine, but when I start the second, or more, threads, the FileVisitor methods for the first thread are being ignored or being called with an incorrect file. The Files.walkFileTree() is a static method. I specify a new FileVisitor implementation for each thread, but to no avail. I find that the Files.walkFileTree() is about 65% faster than other methods. How can I make this multi-Threaded?

Happy Holidays and Thank you.

Peter Jerkewitz

Sample Code:

```
ArrayList<Path> seeds = new ArrayList<>();   // This is where we are going to start looking 


private void launchTreeWalkers() {
  
 ArrayList<Path> effectivelyFinalPath = this.seeds;   // Physical drives on the computer ie  C:\ D:\ E:\ ...   
  int[] index = new int[1];       //  Effectively Final
  this.twThreads = new Thread[ effectivelyFinalPath.size() ];  // TreeWalkerThreads 
  
  for ( int i=0; i < effectivelyFinalPath.size(); i++ ) {
    index[i] = i; 
    
    this.twThreads[i] = new Thread( new Runnable() { 
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                               try {
                                tTreeWalker2( effectivelyFinalPath.get( index[0]) );
                              } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                              }
                             }
                           }
                         );
    
    this.twThreads[i].setDaemon( true );  // So the thread will die when the parent dies.
    this.twThreads[i].setName("Tree Walker");
    this.twThreads[i].start();
  }  
  
  Display.fmt("%1$,d Tree Walker thread%2$s %3$s been started.", box( this.twThreads.length ), Aide.plural(this.twThreads.length), Aide.hasHave( this.twThreads.length ) ); 
}

/** A walkFileTree thread   */
void tTreeWalker( Path startingPath ) throws Exception {
    
  @SuppressWarnings("resource")  // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when closing FileSystem  
  FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();   

  Files.walkFileTree( fileSystem.getPath( startingPath.toString() ), new FileVisitorImpl()); 
}


/** */
public class FileVisitorImpl implements FileVisitor<Path> {
  
  @Override   // Called before a directory visit.
  public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory( Path directory, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
    Locate.this.folderCountLA.increment();  // Long Adder

    if ( isMatch( excludeFolders, directory ))
      return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;

    Locate.this.foldersSelectedLA.increment(); 
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override   // Called after a directory visit is complete.
  public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory( Path dir, IOException exc ) throws IOException {
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override    // This method is called for each file visited. The basic attributes of the files are also available.
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    Locate.this.fileCountLA.increment();

    if ( ! isMatch( excludeFiles, file  ) ) {
      FileOfInterest foi = new FileOfInterest( file );
      
      try { 
        if (( probZips ) && ( foi.isCompressedFile() )) { 
          foundFilesQ.put( foi );
          //TODO  Zip handler goes here 
          
        } else if ( isMatch( selectFiles, file  ) ) {   
          Locate.this.filesSelectedLA.increment();
          foundFilesQ.put( foi );   // Blocking if the Q is full.    
        }

      } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) { // We do not expect this to ever happen.
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override   // If the file visit fails for any reason, the visitFileFailed method is called.
  public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed( Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {

    if ( ! isMatch( knownFailures, file ) ) { // Ignore known failures 
      String msg = exc.toString();

      if ( msg.contains( "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" )) {
        Locate.this.accessDeniedLA.increment();

        if ( showAccessDenied ) 
          Display.fmt("visitFileFailed  %s", exc.toString() );
      } else {
        Locate.this.failuresLA.increment();
        Display.fmt("visitFileFailed  %s", exc.toString() );        
      }
    }  

    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }
}  // End of FileVisitorImpl
```

Comment: It should be possible to call `Files.walkFileTree()` from multiple threads, _if_ you pass in distinct `FileVisitor` instances. Can you show us some code how your `FileVisitor`s are implemented and how you create the threads and your `FileVisitor` instances?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. In trying to fool java by creating Effectively  Final variables as arrays to use in the creation of the runnable was biting me. As I was creating 4 threads in my test case, all 4 threads were running on the same drive, the last one entered. They were not getting used in the order, and at the time, in which I created the runnable. I solved the problem by letting the thread access an AtomicInteger to index the array containing the drives. I also created the FileVisitorImpl in the thread.
Thanks and Happy New Year.
Peter Jerkewitz